# Is there a method to learn which grammatical gender a noun in French has?

Tags: french, grammatical-gender

In French, some nouns are considered male and some female (le/la). Is there a way which can help me understand which grammatical gender to use with which noun?

Comment: So you're looking for a means of remembering or determining which gender to use for which objects?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, to be honest. Do you mean to ask when to use which, or how to hear whish one is being spoken? Or something else? Do you mean something like fiancé/fiancée, or gender of nouns?

Comment: @YviDe Yes, the gender of nouns. Some **things** are considered male and some, like an orange, as female.

Comment: The question belongs to [FL](http://french.stackexchange.com). Might have been already asked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because language-specific questions do not belong here.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because language-specific questions belong here (as long as they're about the learning process and not the language itself).

Comment: Cross-site overlap isn't bad. If we establish that questions about learning specific languages are on-topic - and the meta discussion seems to indicate that so far, that's the consensus - there's no reason for us to move a perfectly fine question elsewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen; meta discussion hasn't indicated that these questions are off-topic. Why kill them now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because based on the question and answers, this topic of discussion is only applicable to the French language, not to any other languages nor language in general. As such, it belongs on French Language SE.

Comment: @user3169 So why does that make it off-topic? See my comments and Gilles' comment above.

Comment: This is being discussed here: [Are questions about individual languages on-topic?](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/4/106). In it, "Questions shouldn't be about the language's spelling/syntax/semantics/etc". I think grammar rules fall into this category. Another consideration, can the information in the answers be applied to other languages? For example, if I substitute "French" with "German", would the information still be applicable?

Comment: @user3169 “Learn the article with the noun” works for both languages (but it doesn't apply to all languages with genders, e.g. for some languages with language-correlated declensions the gender comes naturally). The remaining 90% of the answers here wouldn't be applicable to German. Not that it matters — by now we've settled that language-specific questions are fine. Note that there's a [similar question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2616) on [french.se] and it's getting different answers — the answers on French.SE do language analysis but don't get into the learning process.

Comment: @Gilles About "we've settled that language-specific questions are fine", where is that documented?

Comment: @user3169 http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-individual-languages-on-topic/4#4 (+20/-2 answer in favor, while the top answer against scores 0, that's pretty close to consensus)

Comment: @Gilles But as I pointed out before, even there it says that language specific grammar questions are off-topic. In any case, hopefully the "What topics can I ask about here?" in the Help Center can get decided and filled in soon (beyond the usual SE ones)..

Comment: @user3169 It's not about grammar, though; it's about *learning* grammar.

Comment: See also the question [Beyond memorisation and time, how can you master grammatical gender in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17381/11052) on French Language SE, posted in January 2016.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### You can't, really

As I was learning French (English is my first language) the idea of gender of objects can be difficult to grasp. Genders are pretty much arbitrary and is something you just have to remember with each word (this means remembering it as *"une fenêtre"* rather than *"fenêtre"*).

You can also always listen for a [*liaison*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)). But usually when speaking with a fluent speaker this can be quite subtle, and difficult to listen to.

### General Rules

That said, they are *some general*  patterns which can be used to distinguish the gender of a noun but these **are not rules**, and are only generally followed:

- Things originating in France *tend* to be feminine. e.g. `une crêpe`, or `une pizza`
- Things originating in America *tend* to be masculine e.g. `Un burger`

**BIG DISCLAIMER:** These **are not rules at all**, these are just observations I have made.

---

#### Spelling

Nouns ending in the following tend to be masculine:

- `ge`
- `le` (that aren't `-lle`, `-ole`, `-ale`, or `-ule`)
- `me`
- `re` (that isn't `-ure`)
- `phe`
- `age` source: @bleh

Nouns ending in the following tend to be feminine:

- `on`
- `é`
- `eur`

[[source]](http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/gender/rule.html)

Feminine nouns tend to have `e` at the end too but *many* masculine nouns also have `e` at the end

---

While some genders *tend* to have certain endings, there isn't any definite cut and dry to determine the gender of a word without memorizing it. You *can* memorize some common endings though to make better guesses. [This question on French.SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2616/7385) might provide more information on this.

Comment: Note that -age words are all masculine

Comment: Are you aware of papers such as those in my answer which appear to differ with your answer: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/90/90?

Comment: @bleh [Not all of them, only most of them](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/is-there-any-general-rule-to-determine-the-gender-of-a-noun-based-on-its-spellin/16781#16781). For `-re`, there's technically a masculine majority but just barely. Ditto for the feminine majority of `-é`.

Comment: Where did you find that rule about “things originating in France/America”? As far as I can tell, it's completely bogus.

Comment: @Gilles ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ just from my personal experience, I have a disclaimer on that but I guess I'll need to bold it some more.

Comment: I always thought that hamburgers came from Hamburg... but apparently there is controversy around that. (They *could* also come from [Hamburg, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburg,_New_York).)

Answer (score 9):

#### Yes; rules exist, but they predict gender mostly with at least 80% (but not 100%) accuracy.To see what the rules are, please see the Linguistics papers below.

[The other answer here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/45/90) troubles me because it does not state all the detailed rules discovered in the Linguistics papers below, and so may discourage French learners from benefitting from rules discovered by linguists by possibly misleading them into losing hope and relying on only memorisation.

May I repeat my answer to [a similar question on FSE](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16778/1995):
See

- [*Predictability in French gender attribution:
  A corpus analysis* by Roy Lyster](http://personnel.mcgill.ca/files/roy.lyster/Lyster2006_JFLS.pdf)

I quote from the last paragraph (from p 22 of the PDF of 24 pages above) which answers your question more optimistically:

> Gender  attribution  rules  based  on  noun  endings,  given  their  reliability  and
> systematicity, are worthy of more attention in French reference books and French
> L2
> classrooms. The foregoing corpus-based study confirmed that predictive rules for
> gender attribution do exist and apply to as many as
> 80
> per cent of the nearly
> 10,000
> nouns included in the analysis. More importantly, classroom studies have demonstrated that gender attribution rules are both teachable and learnable. Regardless of
> age, L2
> learners can benefit from form-focused instructional activities that promote
> awareness of gender attribution rules and that provide opportunities for practice
> in associating grammatical gender with orthographic representations of constituent
> rhymes of literally thousands of nouns—both animate and inanimate alike.

- [*Adult L2 Acquisition of French
  Grammatical Gender:
  investigating
  sensitivity to phonological and
  morphological gender cues*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecsisso/docs/honoursThesis.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

Grammatical gender in French is pretty much arbitrary. There's not much to understand. Sorry.

The usual tip when learning a language with (mostly) arbitrary grammatical gender like French or German is to **always learn the article with the noun**. When you learn the word for *car*, learn “la voiture” or “une voiture”. I think I the definite article is taught more often, but it has a downside of hiding the gender if the word starts with a vowel sound: better learn “un arbre” than “l'arbre”. Make sure you understand the pronunciation of the indefinite article though: “une arme” and “un arbre” only differ by the vowel sound (and the noun itself), since the E in *une* is silent and the N in *un* is sounded due to the *liaison* with the following vowel.

Nouns that specifically designate male people (or animals) are masculine. Ditto for females and feminine nouns. (There are a few exceptions with professions that are traditionally gendered.) These nouns usually come in pairs, e.g. “père/mère” (father/mother), “acteur/actrice” (actor/actress), “chat/chatte” (male/female cat). With such pairs, apart from a few common words, the male and female forms differ only by a suffix, the female suffix always ends with `-e`, and the suffixes mostly follow the same patterns as for adjectives.

Apart from that, you can't rely on the meaning of the word. Even if two nouns are synonyms, that doesn't make it more likely that they have the same gender.

You can **sometimes** rely on the **ending** of the word. [Many word endings are strongly gendered](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/is-there-any-general-rule-to-determine-the-gender-of-a-noun-based-on-its-spellin/16781#16781). You may want to learn the most common ones, but I'm not convinced of the effectiveness of this approach: that's one more arbitrary classification to learn, and most classes have exceptions that you'd need to learn anyway.

I think (but I have no data or personal experience to support it) that it would be more effective to learn nouns on an individual basis. Once you know a critical mass of nouns, you can start looking for patterns: if you're unsure about the gender of a noun, try to think of a few words with the same ending; if they all have the same gender then chances are that the noun you're wondering about has the same gender.

What works better than endings is **suffixes**. Many suffixes have a single gender. If a word is built from a stem and a suffix, then once you recognize the suffix, you know the gender of the noun. For example, *-tion* is exclusively a feminine suffix, so any word built with that suffix is feminine, e.g. you don't need to learn words like *vasoconstriction* or *mobilisation* to know their gender. But there are a couple of words that just happen to end with those letters (e.g. *cation* is not *ca-* + *-tion*, *gestion* is not *ges-* + *-tion*), and they can be of either gender. (In this case, recognizing the suffix also tells you the pronunciation of the word: the suffix *-tion* is pronounced [sjɔ̃], but the letters “tion” are otherwise pronounced [tjɔ̃].)

Answer (score 0):

On a more practical note, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iHCwiV-v7RLVRLVVZxX0xQQnM/view?pref=2&pli=1) is a cheat sheet for french gender, and [the accompanying article](http://www.languagecrawler.com/2015/06/cheat-sheet-for-learning-gender-of.html) suggests that *"glancing at this seven-page chart every once in a while helped solidify things"*.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn the grammatical gender is by practice and by using a French dictionary where *nf* refers to "nom féminin" (feminine noun) and *nm* refers to "nom musculin" (masculine noun).

Please note that the grammatical gender is sometimes confusing. I speak French and Arabic (native language), and there are some objects which are feminine in Arabic and masculine in French e.g. airplane, and vice versa e.g. chair.

Comment: Could you add which "method" you propose? "Practice" is too vague.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Practice for me is using French in a daily basis. e.g. Watching TV and movies in French, reading novels. By doing that we will be familiarized with the grammatical gender of the most used nouns.